# Returning results after Post PHP

Tags: php

I have a script that loops through 3 files.
Each file posts data to a api and returns a result, either Accepted or Rejected in variable $result.

On a Accepted response the script stops running and echo out the result.
On a Rejected it echo's out the rejected response and carries on to the next file.

The problem is : Lets say all 3 files give a Rejected reponse , it echo's out 3 rejected responses.

How can i only echo out a single generic response if it does not get a Accepted Response.

```
foreach($getSeq as $key){

        $fileName = $key->file;
        include_once 'Lenders/' . $fileName;

        if($result == 'Accepted'){

            echo 'Accepted';
            break;

        }
        if($result == 'Rejected'){

            echo 'Rejected';
        }


    }
```

Comment: What if 1 accept and 2 reject, what happens?

Comment: i dont understand the question, you could just break out of the `foreach` as you did with `Accepted`??

Comment: @ImAtWar If OP breaks at the the first reject, OP will not reach the "3 reject responses"

Comment: Move the output to after the loop - and inside increase counters or set flags, so that after the loop you can decide what to output based on that.

Comment: @Swellar, as soon as there is an Accept the script stops running "break;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with array() like below:

```
<?php
    $resultArr = array(); // suppose we insert below Accepted = 1 and Rejected = 0
    foreach($getSeq as $key){

        $fileName = $key->file;
        include_once 'Lenders/' . $fileName;

        if($result == 'Accepted'){
            echo "Accepted";
           $resultArr[] = 1;
           break;

        }
        if($result == 'Rejected'){
            $resultArr[] = 0;
        }
    }

    if(!in_array(1, $resultArr)){
        echo 'Rejected';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is specifically for 3 reject response

```
$failed = 0;
foreach($getSeq as $key){
    $fileName = $key->file;
    include_once 'Lenders/' . $fileName;

    if($result == 'Accepted'){

        echo 'Accepted';
        break;

    }
    if($result == 'Rejected'){
        $failed++;
    }


}

if($failed == 3) {
    echo "Rejected";
}
```

You didn't said if what will happens to other ratio ***(1A:2R, 2A:1R)***, so I just created it for 3 rejects